# Determining size of printed page in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA is there a way to determine the width in units of a printed page?

Example pseudo-code is as follows:

```
Dim remainingWidth as Double

remaningWidth = <property that gives printed page width> - _  
                ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftMargin - _  
                ActiveSheet.PageSetup.RightMargin - _  
                Range("A:H").Width
```

Answer (score 1):

[Here are all the members of PageSetup.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb242400.aspx).  My initial thought is to write a function that takes in Orientation and PaperSize and returns the page width.  For example:

```
If ActiveSheet.Orientation = xlLandscape And ActiveSheet.PaperSize = xlPaperLetter Then
    dblPaperWidth = 15840 '11 inches in twips
Else
    ...
End If
```