# Excel VBA set default to not split images in two when printing

Tags: excel, vba, image, printing

I am working on a project in VBA that takes a load of data from our online system, does a lot of formatting, and then presents it in ready to print forms that must fit with an SOP template in a brand new workbook. As a result, there must be a picture on each at the bottom of the rows of data (note this is not a footer).

Unfortunately, when printing, if the picture ends up being inserted near a page break, the image is split in two. Does anyone know any vba cde or tutorials that can help me tell Excel to just move the image to the next page and not to split it in two? I've had an explore with printer settings and page setup but so far haven't seen anything appropriate.

My current code is:

```
For each xWorksheet in ActiveWorkbooks.Worksheets
    lastrow = xWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Range("A" & lastrow + 3).Select 
    xWorksheet.Pictures.Insert("filepath\file name.jpg").Select
Next xWorksheet
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the print area (which can be found here: [Determining size of printed page in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822294/determining-size-of-printed-page-in-excel-vba)) and check that each of the image dimensions are within a multiple of that area.